# How to Host Web API and MVC application on Same Address

Tags: .net, api, iis, model-view-controller, hosting

I have one .NET Solution which has two projects one for MVC app and the other one for APIs.

I need one help regarding the hosting on IIS, where I can deploy both app on same server without changing the address or port.

I wanted to host both app in such way so that I don't need to change the API ajax url in MVC application. What I means is

In MVC, to call the Web API I have used ajax call (url:"/api/LoginAPI/CheckUser")
Note: I have 50+ ajax call on application.

I want to make ajax call by simply adding "/API/" as a suffix and it should be able to call my API and respond as expected result without any issues like (API not found or path is not correct)

I am bit sure that it could be possible but need more expert advice to make sure that I am thinking in a right way.

Please provide your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say , you have two projects ,one is API and second is MVC . API project do also support all .net MVC Features like it does gives all default references of MVC (library refernce) . 
[image: API project includes all MVC dll by default]

1st Way

You just copy following elements in your API project .

All Models,
Controllers
All Views
All CSS Files
All JS Files 
all the refence of mvc project and give this to API project .

Also dont forget to include in your project . This will works for make this single project .

2nd Way

Just Build your MVC project and give refence to API Project .
and Move 
Views 
CSS
JS
in your API project .

3rd Way .

you can create Virtual Directories to have two application on single domain.

Comment: Perfect @Nikunj
Thanks :)

Comment: I have followed your third step and getting this error:    vendors.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8182/api/LoginAPI/CheckUser 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: {Message: "An error has occurred.",…}
ExceptionMessage: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
ExceptionType: "System.NullReferenceException"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at CDS_V1_Api.Controllers.LoginAPIController.CheckUser(UserInfo obj)
↵   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)